# JOIN from a second table based on Random record from a third

Tags: mysql

table1 > galleries  | each identified by a distinct id

table2 > images     | images within a gallery

table3 > galImgLink | each record links an image to a gallery

```
select 
  galId,
  galName 
from 
  galleries 
limit 
  0, 10
```

join an image to each record selected above by selecting a random record from the links table

```
select 
   lnkImgId 
from 
   galImgLink 
where 
    lnkGalId = galId 
ORDER BY 
  RAND() 
LIMIT 
  0, 1
```

and then fetching the related image from the images table

```
select 
  imgFile,
  imgTitle
from 
  Images 
where 
  imgId = lnkImgId and
  imgStatus = 'active'
```

How do i combine these into a single query?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the following would work:

```
SELECT galleries.galId, galleries.galName, Images.imgFile
FROM galleries
JOIN Images
ON Images.imgId = (
    SELECT lnkImgId
    FROM galImgLink
    WHERE lnkGalId = galleries.galId
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link the tables via joins. I'm not as familiar with mysql as with t-sql, but the following should at least get you close.

```
select Images.imgFile, galImgLink.lnkImgId, galleries.galId, galleries.galName
from Images
inner join galImgLink on Images.imgId = galImgLink.lnkImgId
inner join galleries on galImgLink.linkGalId = galleries.galId
limit 0, 10
```

Looking further at your post, it looks like you want to grab 10 galleries with 1 random image for each, so you may need a correlated subquery:

```
select galleries.galId, galleries.galName,
(
select Images.imgFile
from Images
inner join galImgLink on Images.imgId = galImgLink.lnkImageId
where galImgLink.galId = galleries.galId
order by rand()
limit 0, 1
) as imgFile
from galleries
limit 0, 10
```